# Closure template - if condition string contains

Tags: google-closure-templates

I would like to write an if condition and check if a variable contains a certain string and then  write some logic.

if i have a variable say 
@param activity

How can I check that variable activity contains the string "abc"?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation (https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/functions_and_directives), there is the `strContains` method:

`strContains(str, subStr)` - Checks whether a string contains a particular substring.

```
{if strContains($activity, 'abc')}
    // ...
{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you browse [Closure Templates Documentation](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/overview), you should be able to find what you're looking for, especially the `if` section.  Regardless, here's an example:

```
{namespace com.company.my}

/**
 * My Template 
 * @param activity
 */
{template .main}
    {if $activity == 'abc'}
        //do stuff
    {/if}
{/template}
```

Comment: In the question "abc" can be a substring of $activity